# Input box value display , must not allow user to alter

Tags: php, inputbox

Hi all I'm processing membership with standard Pay to membership which is predefined.

After selecting the membership option the standard Pay is displayed in the membership form.

I don't want the user to alter the value of Pay. What i do for it any options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is `readonly="readonly"`

Adding this to a text input field prevents it from being edited in the browser.  Please note you *cannot and should not rely on any client-side changes for data security*.  You would be better off storing the value in a session and showing the user the value as just text, no input field.

[More Info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp)

Comment: readonly fields can still be edited in Firebug or other similar tools. You definitely need to validate that data server side.